# How can i solve this error:"Column 'ASSET' does not belong to table ."?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

How can i solve this error:"Column 'ASSET' does not belong to table ." ? i really learn it is belong this table: i want to do that:

```
if(mydataset.hasgot(dr["asset"].tostring())) <br>
{<br>
// do something<br>
}<br>
```

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr_ = tbl.NewRow();

                if (ds.Tables[0].Columns.Contains(dr_["ASSET"].ToString()))
                         dr_["ASSET"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["ASSET"].ToString(); //dr["ASSET"].ToString();
                  tbl.Rows.Add(dr_);
            }

            DataSet ds_ = new DataSet();
            ds_.Tables.Add(tbl);
```

my error:"Column 'ASSET' does not belong to table .".

Please look:

```
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Contains(dr_["ASSET"].ToString())
```

how can I control my columns which are includes "Asset"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dr_["ASSET"].ToString()` returns a string representation of whatever happens to be in the DataRow `dr_` in column named "ASSET", which is obviously not what you need. Therefore, here's the correct one:

```
if(ds.Tables[0].Columns.Contains("ASSET"))
```